# c++ regex::match_type_flag a.k.a. syntax_option_type

Tags: c++, regex, flags

Does anyone know the type of boost::???::syntax_option_type?
Can't find it in the source nor on the internet. But I need it!
If no-one knows, does a `unsigned int` work well with converting between those two types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) to look through the source code you can see in `regbase.hpp`:

```
typedef ::boost::regbase::flag_type syntax_option_type;
```

and

```
typedef unsigned int flag_type;
```

so it's a UINT.

Comment: It doesn't work. The compiler complains that it can't convert unsigned int to boost::match_flag_type.

Comment: In match_flags.hpp you can see 'typedef match_flags match_flag_type;' where match_flags is an enum. You should be able to just cast it to a UINT, e.g. UINT type = (UINT)flag;

Comment: Thank you, I must have done something wrong, now it casts fine.

Answer (score 0):

`match_flag_type` and `syntax_option_type` are two different type names that are used in different contexts and mean different things. I can't think of any reason to convert between them. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to define custom flags like match_default for my wrapper class around the boost::regex class. So more specific: What is the type of variable boost::match_default?

Comment: @Tim - the type of `match_default` is `match_flag_type`. That should be in the documentation.

Comment: I know. But that is a typedef. I need the original type. Like a std::bitmap<x> or an unsigned long?

Comment: The point of using a typedef is to insulate code from changes in implementation. If you use the actual type you'll have to change it if the type is changed in the future. For `std::regex` the bitmask types can be `std::bitmap` or an integral type or an enumerated type.